# virtual function in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I was doing a output question in C++ , I didn't get the logic behind the following problem can anyone just give a clear idea for the same.

```
Class Base{

 public :
       virtual void fun(){
          cout<<"Base Class public function "<<endl;
            }
};

class Derived:public Base{
       private:
         void fun(){
          cout<<"Derived class private function ";
           }
};


int main(){
    Base *bp=new Derived();
    bp->fun();
}
```

output for the above program is :
**Derived class private function**

I am not able to get how we are able to call private function of the class.

Comment: this is a veeery veeery bad practice, see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-inherited-public.html

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), please.

Comment: @IosifM. Huh? `fun` is implicitly `virtual` in the derived class and the OP describes the output for dynamic dispatch (not hiding). Accessibility is not considered for overriding.

Comment: i was referring to making `fun` private

Comment: Access checking is done based on the static type at the call site. You're calling `fun()` through `Base*` and `fun` is public in `Base`.

Comment: @IosifM. Ah, ok. This FAQ uses the term "hide" in another sense than the C++ Standard. I thought it was referring to *name hiding*, rather than *making it private*.

Comment: @Rahul Apart from what jrok said, FYI, the base class destructor must be virtual if the static type of operand is different from the dynamic type. Or else the program has undefined behavior. The static type of `bp` is `Base *` while the dynamic type is `Derived *`.

Comment: @Mahesh You forgot the `delete` in your remark ;) *the base class dtor must be virtual if the static type of the **object to be deleted** is different from the dynamic type, otherwise UB*. Detail: the only type `bp` has is `Base*`, whereas there is a static and dynamic type of the expression `*bp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us analyze the calling code

```
int main(){
    Base *bp=new Derived();
    bp->fun();
}
```

Here, when you code bp->run(), two things happen.

1) Whether fun is part of class of bp object and is public

2) Binding of "fun" call.

1st, happens during compilation. When checking whether fun is callable, compiler just check the class of bp which is "Base" here and "fun" is part of Base and is public.

For 2nd, since fun is virtual, function binding doesn't happen at compile time. Instead compiler inserts some code which make sure "fun" of "Derived" is called at runtime.